# SSL for different servers behind single ADSL Router

Tags: networking, router, ssl, dsl

I would be glad to find out the ideas how/if one could make two self-hosted servers available online (with SSL) behind a single DSL router.

Setup:

1. Registered domain, by one of the cloud providers
2. Single (A)DSL Connection and the router at home
3. Two different "servers" in home network

If possible,I would like to make them both separately available (with SSL) online.
I know I could use some dynamic DNS service to setup forwarding of the requests to the subdomain to one of the servers. However the ADSL Router can only share single incoming port with one host.
So if I use the 443 port for one server, then would have to use some other port for the second one.

AFAIK, the DNS records could not use any port information. Thus i can not simply redirect the request for different subdomains to the same IP with different port numbers.

Should there be a solution to this, could you please share or point me to one?

Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of proxy. From the router forward all traffic to one server.

Then this server can decide based on the subdomain for which server the traffic is and proxy it.

This can be installed on either server (or a third one if you prefer separation)

Comment: Thanks, that was one of ideas of mine. The only problem is it then makes one of them depending on the other. Especially in case u need to perform some tasks with downtime on the first one, the second one will not be reachable at that point.

Comment: You could install a proxy on both and switch the IP on the router for planned downtimes. But you will always have some point of failure until you build a cluster with HA and 2 routers and 2 internet connections and 2 power-lines and redundant power-supplys...